# Calculator bug only outputting equation not answer

Tags: java, debugging, calculator

When the code is ran and inputs are entered the output which is supposed to solve the equation only prints the equation that was previously entered. Please note that the notes within the code are largely incorrect as they are from a earlier iteration of the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // introduces the user to the programme
    System.out.println("Welcome to my calculator test");
    System.out.println("Function inputs; + to add numbers, - to subtract numbers, * to multiply, / to devide, ^ to power,# to square root.");

    //creates a Scanner
    Scanner reader0 = new Scanner(System.in);
    //promts the user for an input
    System.out.println("Please enter first number"); 
    String a = reader0.nextLine();
    reader0.close();
    char test = 'x';

    String test1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length (); i++ ){
        test = a.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(test) || test == ('.')){
            System.out.println(test);
            test1 = test1+""+test;
        }
        else if (test == '+' ||test == '-' ||test == '*' ||test == '/' ||test == '#' ||test == '^'){
            char b = a.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(test1);
    double number = Double.parseDouble(test1);

    // checks that if the user intends to squareroot the first number
    if (test == '#'){
        // square roots the first number
        System.out.println(java.lang.Math.sqrt(a));
    }
    else{

        //creates a Scanner
        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        //promts the user for an input
        System.out.println("Please enter Second number");
        String c = reader2.nextLine();
        reader2.close();

        // checks if user wanted to add
        if (test == '+'){
            // adds the two numbers
            System.out.println(a+c);
        }
        //checks if user wanted to subtract
        else if (test == '-'){
            // subtracts the two numbers
            //System.out.println(a-c);
        }
        //checks if user wanted to multiply
        else if (test == '*'){
            // multiplies the two numbers
            //System.out.println(a*c);
        }
        //checks if the user wanted to divide
        else if (test == '/'){
            // devides the two numbers
            //System.out.println(a/c);
        }
        //checks if the user wants to power the numbers
        else if (test == '^'){
            // powers the first number by the second number
            //System.out.println(java.lang.Math.pow(a,c));
        }
        // if the programme is unsure what the user intended then a error message will be printed to screen
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR.UserInputForFunctionVoid");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with solving this issue will be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Please note that the notes within the code are largely incorrect as they are from a earlier iteration of the code` - please make some effort to remove irrelevant comments from the code you posted.

Comment: `System.out.println(a+c);` a and c are Strings, so the `+` operator does not perform numeric addition.

Comment: "only prints the equation that was previously entered" - This shouldn't compile.

Comment: [How can I find the sum of two numbers which are in String variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5593492) See also: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this won't compile as `Math.sqrt(a)` as `String` cannot be converted to `double` like this. I also don't think it will work as expected even if `a` was a `double`.

You are better off reading in an `int` or `double` in the first place, something like `double a = reader0.nextDouble();`.

You could shorten your code too a little, by reading in the first number, then reading in the operator. Then check if the square root is required (as I guess you don't need the second number at this stage), and then asking for the second number.

I would also declare my result initially (`double result = 0.0;`) and then just print that at the end.

So after you check for the `#`, just put the rest in the `else`:

```
if (operator.equals("+")) {
            result = a + b;
        } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            result = a - b;
        } 
        //and so on...
```

**Note:** your result may end up with x amount of places after the decimal point, so perhaps consider using `String.format("%.2f", result)` or something similar.

**Extra note:** You may also consider using a `switch` in place of the `if...else if`.

Here is a [partial demo](https://ideone.com/hrodSd).